# Frequency tables with weighted data in R

Tags: r, weighted, frequency-distribution

I need to calculate the frequency of individuals by age and marital status so normally I'd use:

```
    table(age, marital_status)
```

However each individual has a different weight after the sampling of the data. How do I incorporate this into my frequency table?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use function `svytable` from package `survey`, or `wtd.table` from `rgrs`.

**EDIT :** `rgrs` is now called `questionr` :

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), wt = c(30, 10, 20, 40))

library(questionr)
wtd.table(x = df$var, weights = df$wt)
#  A  B 
# 40 60
```

That's also possible with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
count(x = df, var, wt = wt)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#        var     n
#     <fctr> <dbl>
#   1      A    40
#   2      B    60
```

Comment: Excellent, the wtd.table option suits me perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the sake of completeness, using base R:

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), wt = c(30, 10, 20, 40))

aggregate(x = list("wt" = df$wt), by = list("var" = df$var), FUN = sum)
```

> `var wt`
> `1   A 40`
> `2   B 60`

Or with the less cumbersome formula notation:

```
aggregate(wt ~ var, data = df, FUN = sum)
```

> `var wt`
> `1   A 40`
> `2   B 60`

Answer (score 4):

Another solution from package `expss`:

```js
    df <- data.frame(var = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), wt = c(30, 10, 20, 40))
    
    library(expss)
    
    fre(df$var, weight = df$wt)

 | df$var | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | ------ | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |      A |    40 |            40 |      40 |           40 |                      40 |
 |      B |    60 |            60 |      60 |           60 |                     100 |
 | #Total |   100 |           100 |     100 |          100 |                         |
 |   <NA> |     0 |               |       0 |              |                         |
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` you could do:

```
# using the same data as Victorp
setDT(df)[, .(n = sum(wt)), var] 

   var  n
1:   A 40
2:   B 60
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tablefreq from package freqweights:

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), wt = c(30, 10, 20, 40))

library(freqweights)

tablefreq(df, "var", "wt")

A tibble: 2 x 2
var    freq
<fct> <dbl>
1 A        40
2 B        60
```

Comment: What happened to package `freqweights`? No longer on CRAN

Answer (score -1):

Use package weights and function wpct

```
require(weights)
df <- data.frame(var = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), wt = c(30, 10, 20, 40))
wpct(df$var, df$wt)

 A   B 
0.4 0.6
```